# How to escape a double quotes, inside a double quotes, inside a single quotes in PHP/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

So I have a PHP code that generates a portion of HTML/JavaScript code like below:

```
$link = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" 
         class="btn btn-read btn-flat" 
         onclick="showLoginLightBox(0,2);">Click Here</a>';
```

This works fine, but I want to replace the second parameter "2" with a text. So I have tried:

```
$link = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" 
         class="btn btn-read btn-flat" 
         onclick="showLoginLightBox(0,\"active\");">Click Here</a>';
```

This just gives me an error saying `SyntaxError: invalid escape sequence`

I have many combinations `\'` and `\"` and others but nothing works. Can someone help me here?

Comment: [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode)/[`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML you can use `&quot;` instead of `"`
and `&apos;` instead of `'`

Comment: In HTML one **must** use `&quot;` to encode `"` in element attributes. It is optional only in the elements' content.

Answer (score 1):

This is by FAR the simplest

```
?>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-read btn-flat" 
     onclick="return showLoginLightBox(0,2);">Click Here</a>
```

and have

```
function showLoginLightBox(..) {
  ...
  return false;
}
```

or EVEN better:

```
?>
<a href="#" id="login" class="btn btn-read btn-flat" 
  data-parm1="0" data-parm2="2">Click Here</a>
<script>
document.getElementById("login").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  showLoginLightBox(this.dataset.parm1,this.dataset.parm2);
})
<script>
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the string in double quotes and escape the double quotes for each attribute, then use single quotes for the string parameter.

```
$link = "<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" 
         class=\"btn btn-read btn-flat\" 
         onclick=\"showLoginLightBox(0,'active');\">Click Here</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
<?php

$link = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" 
         class="btn btn-read btn-flat" 
         onclick="showLoginLightBox(0,\'active\');">Click Here</a>';
         
echo $link;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the JavaScript needs escaping:

```
$link = '<a href="#" class="btn btn-read btn-flat" onclick="showLoginLightBox(0,\"active\");">Click Here</a>';
```